# How to improve performance of listing files in a Google bucket?

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

I implemented a function in Java Spring Boot to list all images from a bucket with in sum ~12000 assets. In the bucket are ~4000 images stored.

```java
String pathPrefix = "/2021/";
Page<Blob> blobs = storage.list(bucket, Storage.BlobListOption.prefix(pathPrefix));

Predicate<Blob> ONLY_IMAGES = b -> b.getContentType().startsWith("image/");
ArrayList<Blob> images = new ArrayList<>();
for (Blob blob : blobs.iterateAll()) {
    if (ONLY_IMAGES.test(blob)) {
        images.add(blob);
    }
}
```

The runtime of this small filter function is 48 minutes.

**Update**

I had tested the following two approaches.

1. Reducing the amount of requested metadata with:

```java
Storage.BlobListOption.fields(Storage.BlobField.CONTENT_TYPE)
```

2. Parallel processing of blobs with:

```
ArrayList<Blob> imgBlobs = (ArrayList<Blob>) StreamSupport.stream(
    storage.list(bucket, Storage.BlobListOption.prefix(pathPrefix), 
                 Storage.BlobListOption.fields(Storage.BlobField.CONTENT_TYPE))
             .iterateAll().spliterator(), true) 
             .filter(filter) 
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Unfortunately, both approaches did not improve performance.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to improve this?

Thank you.

Comment: There is no direct solution with GCS, you have to rethink the image storage, or to maintain a side index in a database to perform that query fast

Comment: You misunderstood my first recommendation. Limit the request of metadata to objects that have certain file extensions.

Comment: I do not think your second method is requesting blob metadata in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are reading each blob's metadata, one object at a time which results in long processing time - thousands of HTTP requests.

Ideas:

1. Limit the **getContentType()** operation to blobs with certain filename extensions like **jpg**.
2. Rewrite the code to process blobs in parallel.
3. Maintain an external database of bucket contents.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. I had tested the following two approaches:

1. Reducing the amount of requested metadata with: `Storage.BlobListOption.fields(Storage.BlobField.CONTENT_TYPE)`

2. Parallel processing of blobs with:
`ArrayList<Blob> imgBlobs = (ArrayList<Blob>) StreamSupport.stream(storage.list(bucket, Storage.BlobListOption.prefix(pathPrefix), Storage.BlobListOption.fields(Storage.BlobField.CONTENT_TYPE)).iterateAll().spliterator(), true)
.filter(filter)
.collect(Collectors.toList());`

Unfortunately, both approaches did not improve performance.

Comment: @Ben - Edit your question to show what you have tried and the results.